# How to manage windows in cocoa

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I know the question is a bit generic but I guess my issue is generic as well. 
I'm developing a small application in my free time and I decided to do it with Cocoa. It's nice, many things works almost automagically, but sometimes it's quite hard to understand how the framework works.

Lately I'm facing a new problem. I want to manage all the windows of the application from a single class, a front controller basically. I have a main menu and an "Import data" function. When I click it I want to show another window containing a table and call a method for updating the data. The problem is that this method is inside the class that implements the `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol.

How can I have a reference to that class? And more important, which should be the right way to do it? Should I extend the `NSWindow` class so that I can receive an Instance of NSWindow that can control the window containing the table (and then call the method)?

I may find several ways to overcome this issue, but I'd like to know which one is the best practice to use with cocoa.

PS: I know that there are tons of documentations files, but I need 2 lives to do everything I'd like to, so I thought I may use some help asking here :)

Comment: Do you have a `NSWindowController` to manage your windows?  You can always have multiple instance of them in your front controller to manage multiple windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that this method is inside the class that implements the NSTableViewDataSource protocol.
>
> How can I have a reference to that class?

These two sentences don't make sense, but I think I understand what you're getting at.

Instead of subclassing NSWindow, put your import window's controlling logic – including your NSTableViewDataSource methods – into a controller class. If the controller corresponds to a window, you can subclass NSWindowController, though you don't have to.

You can implement `-importData:` as an IBAction in your application delegate, then connect the menu item's selector to importData: on First Responder. That method should instantiate the import window controller and load the window from a nib.

In your import window controller's `-awakeFromNib` or `-windowDidLoad` method, call the method which updates the data.

**Added:**

Here's the pattern I'd suggest using in your app delegate:

```
@property (retain) ImportWindowController *importWC;
```

```
- (IBAction) showImportWindow:(id) sender {
    if (!self.importWC)
        self.importWC =
        [[ImportWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ImportWindow"];
    [self.importWC refreshData];
    [self.importWC.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}
```

Comment: Hi noa, thanks for the answer. What I already did is more or less what you're saying. The problem is that I can't implement the `-importData` method in the app delegate because that method should also update the data on my table even when the window is already loaded, so I can't just rely on updating data when loading the window.

Comment: To update the data on the table I need access to the array containing the data and then access to the tableView instance to call the `-reloadData`method. That's why I was talking about a reference to the instance of the controller class. The reference that is created when the window is loaded and automatically instantiate the delegate class for managing the table.

Comment: Got it. In that case, you need a method like `-refreshData` in the public interface of your import window controller – that's the object that should have a reference to the tableview.

Comment: And you're right, your app delegate needs a reference to the import window controller. Use a property to store a reference to the import window controller – set it when you first instantiate the controller. I posted a little bit of code to give you an idea.

Comment: I know it was going to be easy but somehow I couldn't figure it out!! Thanks a lot for your help! :D